# Catch Specific Exceptions under OLEDBException -2147467259

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, error-handling, oledb

I have an app that uses OleDB to connect to an Access database. I am trying to create some error handling for inserting duplicate records, where there is a unique index.

When this error is thrown I get the error code -2147467259 on the exception. However other errors also give the same error code; Database full, or column missing for example.

Is there a way to determine between these different errors without using the error message itself which every part of me says will be unreliable.

I have looked at `.innerexception`, in the case of inserting duplicates there is no inner exception.

I have also looked at .SQLState property, it appears that this is an old method not really within use in the 4.0 framework. I could apply this but I would likely be using on error, rather than my desired try catch.

My code at the moment:

```
            Try
                Sender.cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As OleDbException

            End Try
```

Comment: **Catch generic error** then do a **query** to check if another record with the **same ID exists**.

Comment: @Adriano Ok I will look into this. It still feels like I could have problems on some of the other errors under this code.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being that guy who insists that your underlying issues is the real issue here... the DB is the real issue here.

I assume that you have some kind of natural key going (otherwise you wouldn't get duplicate key exceptions) rather than a generated key. I would suggest changing the table so you don't need to worry about trying to work out why your insert failed because of a bad PK.

Ive seen something similar to this logic where a colleague implemented a save method as:

```
try
{
    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Which is... bad.

Comment: Welcome to SO :). The table holds test data, the unique key is a date/time. The attempt to catch a duplicate key is to avoid users entering duplicate data. I don't feel like this is a fundamental issue.

Comment: Thanks :) Is the data duplicate based on other fields, or based on the date time? I dont mean in terms of the DBMS, but logically, what makes it a duplicate?

Comment: The duplicate is based date time, there should only be one record per time. These duplicates would be created by someone importing the same data twice.

Comment: Ok, well I dont think there is a specific exception for what you are trying to do. Can I suggest possibly writing a proc to call? Then you can add a transaction to check whether your save action is an Insert or an Update.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is a specific exception, there are 2+ errors caught on this exception I want a method for determining which is thrown. There will never be an update query to this table, only insert/delete. Thanks for your help, I think I have a solution which I will answer with if it works.